# UTC timezone in the OK() function in .NET WebAPI C#

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, utc

I have a .NET `WebAPI` which returns some dates as `JSON`.
I'm using the `Ok()` function which takes the C# DateTime list and convert them into a JSON array.

My requirement is to specify the timezone in any case (even +00:00)

Now, the format I'm using is:

```
jsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "o";
```

which uses the ISO standard and a "Z" to specify UTC.

Unfortunately my web application doesn't understand such convention (I mean, the final "Z") and it requires a timezone offset to be present in any case. 
In other words, I'd like to use a "+00:00" instead of the "Z".

How can I tell `WebAPI` to use such convention?

Previously I had:

```
jsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffzzz";
```

which doesn't had the timezone information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not as easy as one would like - mainly, because the `DateTime` type is [confusing at its best, and wrong at its worst](http://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html).

I would recommend handling only UTC dates on the server (i.e. assuming UTC on any incoming date, saving everything as UTC and returning UTC everywhere) and letting your clients decide if they need to do something about that (e.g. convert to a local time for correct display). Then, it could be as easy as setting

```
jsonSerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff+00:00";
```

i.e. hard-coding the `+00:00` there, since you *know* (by assumption) that it's going to be UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Use [System.DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of Use `System.DateTime` in your return statement (Ok). This will automatically append the `+00:00` the the serialized string (*+00:00 is assuming its a UTC point in time*).

*for Web API 2 and higher, I am not sure about previous versions*

This is also the default date/time format for other Web API extensions like oData.